# Automatically Set Set Product as New to Date for 7 Days

Tags: magento-1.9

how can I have Magento automatically set

> Set Product as New to Date

for 7 days whenever I create a new product, that way I don't have to be manually selecting the dates whenever I create a new product.

Answer (score 1):

You can use event

> catalog_product_save_before

to add value in new from today's date using date function and in new to date after seven days using date function with +7 days.

This is the simple way to achieve this. You can also oveeride controller but better is use event observer. Please follow below step to make module for save date automatically.

Create xml file to register module

> app/etc/modules/Company_Date.xml

add below code to this Company_Date.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Company_Date>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>local</codePool>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Company_Date>
  </modules>
</config>
```

Now create config.xml file in app/code/local/Company/Date/etc/

Add below code to config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Company_Date>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Company_Date>
  </modules>
  <global>
    <helpers>
      <date>
        <class>Company_Date_Helper</class>
      </date>
    </helpers>
    <models>
      <date>
        <class>Company_Date_Model</class>
        <resourceModel>date_mysql4</resourceModel>
      </date>
    </models>
    <events>
      <catalog_product_save_before> <!-- identifier of the event we want to catch -->
        <observers>
          <catalog_product_save_before_handler> <!-- identifier of the event handler -->
            <type>singleton</type> <!-- class method call type; valid are model, object and singleton -->
            <class>date/observer</class> <!-- observers class alias -->
            <method>SaveDate</method>  <!-- observer's method to be called -->
          </catalog_product_save_before_handler>
        </observers>
      </catalog_product_save_before>
    </events>
  </global>
</config>
```

Now create Observer file app/code/local/Company/Date/Model/Observer.php

```
class Company_Date_Model_Observer
{

            public function SaveDate(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
            {
                       $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
                       Mage::log($product->getId(), null, 'mylogfile.log');
                       $product->setNewsFromDate('10/26/2016') //product set as new from 
                       ->setNewsToDate('10/30/2016');  // make date dynamic
            }

}
```

Comment: Can you walk me through on how to use that?

Comment: Do you have magento 1 or magebto 2? I can see your comment you don't have directory after app/code. It should be M2. Please confirm.

Comment: I have Magento 1.9.2.4

Comment: sorry there is some mis-understanding. you need to create directory in app/code/local/PACKAGE/YOUR MODULE. CODEPOOL means local/community

Comment: Wow, I can't find a way to do this, I'm really confused.

Comment: @cubaton3 Please check now. I have update answer. Hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: I don't have Company folders after /local/

Comment: You should create folder Comany in local. I have create company_date module to add logic of automatic date.

Comment: It didn't work, I created the folders and added all the files in.

Comment: I have tested it. It should work. Have you also add file in app/etc/module/?

Comment: Yes, I have added all the files and directories, it isn't working.

Comment: @cubaton3 in the admin goto sysytem->configuration and in the left check  in advance there will be list of all available module. Can you see new module Comapny_Date listed there?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to declare observer in your config.xml

```
app/code/[CODEPOOL]/Company/Extension/etc/config.xml

<global>
     <events>
        <catalog_product_save_after>
            <observers>
                <your_module_save_product_changes>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>your_module/observer</class>
                    <method>setProductdateobserver</method>
                </your_module_save_product_changes>
            </observers>
        </catalog_product_save_after>
    </events>
</global>
```

Now create observer.php file in this location

```
app/code/[CODEPOOL]/Company/Extension/Model/Observer.php

class Company_Extension_Model_Observer
{
    public function setProductdateobserver($observer)
    {
       $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
       // Now right your logic and set new product date
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't have those directories after /app/code/

Comment: You can used any already avilable extension Or create new extension for this.

Comment: @cubaton3 Have you check above things?

Comment: I'm not going to pay for an extension, and I don't know how to execute this myself.

Comment: if you get your solution then mark as answer, so other can also get help :)